# Mysql: usage of each socket adress

Tags: php, mysql, windows, sockets

I am getting this error in `php/mysql : Warning mysql_connect()`. Only one usage of each socket address

```
(protocol/network addresses/ (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306 in ..
```

Please provide me any suggesstion to solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

you should find in httpd.conf or your htaccess file and change setting "keepalivetimeout" minimum not maximum.then restart localserver. if not exists in both file then need to be configure in your local htaccess

Please read following article
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout

Comment: @VinodPuliyadi please make accepted my answer if its helpfull to you